# Indirect installation & activation of minor modes?

Tags: emacs

I recently installed and later uninstalled [elpy](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy) on Emacs. Interestingly, the uninstallation of elpy didn't leave Emacs in its original state, at least as far as I can tell.

1. For example, I am highly confident I did **not** have [Eldoc](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElDoc) installed or enabled by default before installing elpy, but after uninstalling elpy, Eldoc seems to remain enabled by default in my Python buffers. This is quite annoying since Eldoc seems to open a documentation window (a buffer) whenever I leave cursor at the end of a line in any of my Python buffers.
2. Also, indentation in my Python buffers is highlighted, even though that wasn't the case before I installed elpy.

Oddly enough, I am certain I have not modified my `.emacs` at all in the process. Where do these activations come from?

In case it matters, I am using a nightly build of Emacs from yesterday (July 7, 2014).

Comment: Is there anything suspicious in the file pointed to by `custom-file`?

Comment: Thanks @Chris. `custom-file` seems to hold `nil`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why eldoc would stay active, but `elpy` is not just a simple package providing a particular feature, instead it's a package which takes several packages and configures them together in one particular way.

If you install `elpy` from some ELPA archive, Emacs first installs `elpy`'s requirements, which include packages such as `highlight-indentation`.  When you uninstall a package, OTOH, Emacs does not uninstall the package's requirements (because it does not keep track of the difference between packages *you* installed and packages installed to satisfy dependencies).

IOW you might have to uninstall `highlight-indentation` manually.

Comment: Thank you Stefan. Do you know how I can disable `Eldoc` by default? I have tried adding the code that disables it to one of my Python hooks, but it doesn't work: `(defun my-python-mode-hook () 
 (eldoc-mode 0)
  (linum-mode 1)) 
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'my-python-mode-hook) `

Comment: Depends how it's enabled.  By default it's not enabled!  This said, eldoc is not supposed to open a new window/buffer, it should only display info in the echo area, so there seem to be some other issue at play.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes (not always) it uses the minibuffer. I am surprised that adding it to `python-mode-hook` doesn't do the trick.